# How can I copy my whole postgres database to another postgres one?

Tags: postgresql

I have two postgres databases on the same server, a live one and another one which I use as a test database.

Periodically I need to copy my live database (both structure of the tables and their data) into the test one, but everything I've found online only copies table by table. Since I often create new tables in my live db I can't do this, otherwise I'd have to update the job every time.

Anybody knows how can I pull the whole live postgres db into the test postgres one?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.

Example usage would be:

```
$ pg_dump -Fc <database_name> > dumpfile
$ pg_restore <another_database_name> < dumpfile
```

If you want to do this for all database you might want to consider `pg_dumpall`

A bit more can be found in https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/backup-dump.html